# Como atualizar / refresh nos dados usando Android Volley com MySQL?

Tags: android, volley

Sou novo no assunto e novo por aqui, estou exibindo um trecho do código que estou utilizando para teste. Os dados são exibidos normalmente na primeira vez que faço uma consulta através do aplicativo, porém se realizo um novo insert, update, ou delete, os dados não são atualizados no aplicativo, permanece exibindo os dados antigos.

Tenho um app mais completo que estou desenvolvendo porém me deparei com esse erro e travei. Já tentei limpar o cache e desativar mas sem resultado.

```
public void CarregarWebServices()
{
    progresso = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progresso.setMessage("Carregando...");
    progresso.show();
    String url = "https://meu_endreco/arquivo.php";

    jsonObjectReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null,this,this);
    request.add(jsonObjectReq);

}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
{
    progresso.hide();//fechando
    Toast.makeText(this,"Erro: "+error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
{
    progresso.hide();//fechando
    textView.setText(response.toString());//exibindo os dados
}
```

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver meu problema adicionando  **jsonArrayRequest.setShouldCache(false);** e **queue.getCache().clear();**

Além disso adicionei um método GET/POST e o código mesmo que vazio de passagem dos parâmetros:

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            return params;
        }
```

**Segue um exemplo:**

```
public void BuscarJson(String url) {
    // Initialize a new JsonArrayRequest instance
    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            url,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try{
                        for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            //guardando valor retornado na variável
                            String variavel = obj.getString("meu_campo_json");
                            //também poderá adicionar uma lista de valores (ArrayList)

                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Erro: "+error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    ){
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            return params;
        }};

    jsonArrayRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    queue.getCache().clear();
    queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

}

Caso não queria, poderá remover o laço de repetição